# delegate becomes nil inside AFNetworking response block?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to fetch data and I have a delegate in the Service class which could be a UIController. The Service class is responsible for fetching data through AFNetworking classes.

```
//Class Service. 


@interface Service : NSObject {

    __weak id<ServiceDelegate>delegate;

}


- (void) doFetch:(APIInput*) input {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self getLocation:input]];
    NSLog(@"url request is: %@", url);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        //NSLog(@"IP Address: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"origin"]);

        [self.delegate serviceDidComplete:[self allocNewData:JSON]];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                NSError *error, id JSON){

        [self.delegate serviceFailed: error];
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

And in the UIController viewDidLoad: I have the following

```
self.networkService = [[Service alloc] init];
[self.networkService setDelegate:self];
```

Once I run the ios app, self.delegate is nil. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved it. I created a __block variable before setting the operation

```
__block id itsme = self.delegate;

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        //NSLog(@"IP Address: %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"origin"]);

        [itsme serviceDidComplete:[self allocNewData:JSON]];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                NSError *error, id JSON){

        [itsme serviceFailed: error];
    }];
```